# CSRF protection to a view with a download api request

Tags: python, django, rest, csrf

I have this view in my application that calls an api to download a pdf:

```
@login_required
def generateContractPdf(request):
   file_id = request.POST.get('contract')  
   contract_id = request.POST.get('contract')    
   payload = {"file_id": file_id}
   data = {"data": json.dumps(payload, default=str)}
   headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
   brokkr = os.environ.get("BROKKR_ADDRESS", default='localhost')
   response = requests.post('http://'+brokkr+':5000/contract', params=data, headers=headers)

   filename=str(contract_id)+".pdf"
   response = HttpResponse(response.content, content_type='application/pdf')
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'+filename+'"'

   return response
```

But I just realiced that if I dont use render() the csrf doens't work, so this view could be exploited.

How can i transforme it to keep that protection?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `csrf_protect` decorator onto your view for the protection of CsrfViewMiddleware to a view.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
def generateContractPdf(request):
    --- Your logic ---
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to *keep* the CSRF protection. The `csrf_exempt` decorator disables it.

Comment: I think that's the opposite of what I want to do. I want to use the csrf token i send in the form even if it doesnt use render() to return de answer

Comment: I edited my answer, please check it and if it will not work just comment here. :)